# `git` doesn't pass `--help` unto custom scripts

Tags: git

It seems that `git my-custom-script --help` gets intercepted by `git` and, as there is man-page for it, `git` returns the following error

```
man: No entry for git-my-custom-script in the manual.
```

Any idea of how to pass `--help` to the script?

PS1: `-h` and `help` are both passed, so this is specifically about `--help`

PS2: IIRC, `--help` was passed to the script in the past, so was there a `git` update that changed the behavior?

Comment: `git-my-custom-script --help`?

Comment: Or maybe `git my-custom-script -- --help`?

Comment: @Philippe that doesn't work; also, what follows `--` is usually the file path, and with `git` this file may not exist in the working directory, so you cannot check for it easily

Comment: @phd that works, however, it is not a good form and expects the user to know that is a non-native `git` command